# Adding label to menustrip

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label, menustrip

Is it possible to add a lable/toostriplabel to a menustrip in a c# winform? 
I can't find an option to add it dierctly.

I want to add something that describes the status of a program, but I don't want to use a status bar for space.

Comment: You should be able to add a [System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripLabel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstriplabel.aspx).  I think it's not shown at design time because the MenuStrip isn't meant to have labels, it's meant to have MenuItems...  normally when you want labels you use a regular ToolStrip.

Comment: You can copy and paste a ToolStripLabel in the designer or add it in code.  But Microsoft thinks you shouldn't.  Because menus aren't supposed to have labels.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply `ToolStripLabel` is just a `ToolStripItem` and `MenuStrip.Items` is a collection of `ToolStripItem` so you can just add a `ToolStripLabel` to `MenuStrip` normally like this:

```
menuStrip1.Items.Add(new ToolStripLabel("Status"));
```

To control the distance between the `ToolStripLabel` and the `Left-side ToolStripItem`, you can set the `Margin` property of your `ToolStripLabel`, like this:

```
toolStripLabel1.Margin = new Padding(50,3,3,3);
```

Comment: Thanks! this is working. But I think it's easier to copy and paste it as Trevor suggested

Comment: @Jerry I misunderstood your question, if you mean `Drag-n-drop or add ToolStripLabel at design time` (which is a better description than `directly`), I think `copying-n-pasting` looks like the easiest solution. However I don't even understand what `Trevor` said, it's not really clear although I understand how to do the `Copy-n-paste`, first we have to drag-n-drop some `ToolStrip`, add some `ToolStripLabel` to that `ToolStrip` by the designer and then just Copy and Paste.